# log4net not logging to db when published - Multi Project Solution (console app)

Tags: vb.net, log4net

It's a question I see on here but solutions aren't working.

I have a Multi Project Solution set up like so

[image]

The sole purpose of the "Console" is to start/stop the "Controller", the "Controller" the handles the "Plugins".

"Console" is a Console Application the other projects are class libraries.

I've just added log4net to the "Controller" project to write logs to the database.

In DEBUG it works perfectly and logs to SQL.

However once built in release, published and deployed it is failing to log.

I've kept all the log4net config within the Controllers "app.config" and know this is being used because the "app.config" has some other settings present.

**Attempted Solutions** -  ALL WORKING in DEBUG but not Published/Released Version

Changed SQL connection string to a USER & Password from Windows

Changed log4net to separate config file and setting build properties to CONTENT and COPY ALWAYS

Using the below code to configure log4net in either he "AssemblyInfo.vb or the "Contoller.vb" file

```
Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile:="app.config", Watch:=True)
```

Any potential ideas please?

NOTE:

If  I remove the explicit ConfigFile:="app.config" LOGGING DOES NOT WORK

NOTE 2:

Setting an absolute file path on the server for the ConfigFile enabled the Published Installed version to work. Is this the best method?

Comment: Turn on the internal log4net logging and see any errors reported.